# who is http://viyals.com/, and why did I get routed through them to askubuntu.com?

Tags: support, bug

I searched for a ubuntu question, and came to what appeared to be askubuntu.com.  I was going to comment and tried to log in.  It never worked.  I looked at the url and it was viyals.com.
They are registered private.

If they are not affiliated with askubuntu, I suspect they are doing a man in the middle attack. Does anyone know?

Comment: Change your password right away, just in case!

Comment: Even before I posted :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Viyals appears to be some sort of scraper or more likely a site duplicate. My suggestion is to report them using [Stack Exchange's Report function](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), since it seems to fall under the proxy category. [Refer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do) for more info

Comment: Thanks, I will.  Scrapers that duplicate the login page are man in the middle, to me.